# What is the difference between SSO and Oauth?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, single-sign-on

I've been working with authentication providers and custom implementations of authentication at the application level, and I can't still wrap my head around these 2 concepts entirely.

I understand SSO, as the name implies, is to provide a centralized login experience where I can use a single set of credentials to access multiple platforms. While oauth allows users to access resources based on credentials from an authorization server.

If I have a single set of credentials that allow me to access 4 different platforms, that is SSO. But if these 4 platforms allow social login using google for instance, It is basically the same? As I am able to access the same 4 platforms with my single google credentials.

What makes the difference between SSO and oauth if both can be used to provide access to multiple platforms with the same set of credentials, and as I understand both work with some sort of authentication server (I understand SSO has a centralized authorization service or something similar)?

Answer (score 2):

SSO and OAuth are two different protocols that can be used for different purposes.

SSO is a method that allows users to authenticate once and access multiple applications without being prompted to enter their credentials again. This is typically done by an identity provider (IdP) that issues a token to the user, which is then passed to the different applications the user wants to access.

OAuth, on the other hand, is an open standard for authorization (not authentication). It allows users to grant third-party applications access to their resources (e.g. data) without sharing their credentials. OAuth does not provide authentication, but it can be used in conjunction with other protocols, such as SSO, to provide a seamless user experience.

In summary, SSO is used for authenticating users, while OAuth is used for granting access to resources. OAuth can be used as part of an SSO solution, but it is not a replacement for SSO.